# Laravel named routing | Auto generating urls to best possible match

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to name my routes so I can easily generate urls instead of using the url helper function in which I have to type myself.

I am doing this:

```
Route::get('logout', 'PageController@logout')->name('pc');
```

When I do *php artisan route:list* I don't get this named route, instead name column is empty.

What I want is that, whatever views I target through this controller. I want to generate their urls like this.

```
route('pc.logout') OR route('pc.some_other_action')
```

So even if I change the verb to access this controller from the URL address, I don't have to change my url generator. Is this even possible in Laravel? Please also tell how to do this for resource routes.

I am using Laravel 5.3.

Thanks.

EDIT: Next day 1/11/2017

What I am expecting is that like ASP.NET MVC routing, if I tell it to generate a url with given controller and actions, it will generate the possible route to it regardless of the verb or string used to name the route.

**For example**

If I make a url like this

```
route('users.index')
```

Outputs */users*

but if I change the string name users to u, instead of giving me error that name 'users' doesn't exist it should auto generate a url output like this:

Output: */u*

This is a part of ASP.NET MVC routing system, I am expecting to see this here as well.

Comment: Route::get('logout',array('uses'=>'PageController@logout','as'=>'pc')); try like this.

Answer (score 1):

You should write this This will solve your problem

```
Route::get('logout', array('as' =>'pc.logout' ,'uses' => 'PageController@logout'));
```

This might solve your problem

Comment: Updated my question

Answer (score 0):

```
name('pc.logout') OR name('pc.some_other_action')
```

You can try this one.

It is much simpler way to use:

```
Route::get('logout', 'PageController@logout')->name('pc.logout');
```

Or like this:

```
Route::get('logout', 'PageController@logout')->name('pc.some_other_action');
```

can you explain further if this is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you can define the named route as this

```
Route::get('/logout',[                       

'uses'=>'web\PageController@logout',   

'as'=>'pc'
```

]);

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
Route::get('logout',[
    'uses'=>'PageController@logout',
    'as'=>'pc.logout'                     
]);
```